# Is it possible to launch the application powershell application from docker container

Tags: powershell, docker

I am using centos conttainer on Windows.

Now I want to launch Windows application from.

For example,

`start chrome.exe "yahoo.com"`

it opens the chrome from powershell.

Now, I want to launch this from container.

Is it possible to send some commend to powershell within the docker container??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers intrinsically can’t launch other processes on the host.  If this is a key part of your application, you should run it directly on the host.

Comment: thank you ... I gave up my plan and change my strategy. I wanted to make the script which works on both Win and Mac and launchex the browser. So I tried to use docker.